# CRM 2011 - CloseIncidentRequest - Throws Exception when registered on Create Case Post Event

Tags: plugins, registration, crm

I am trying to get a plugin registered on the case ("incident") create post synchronous event to successfully call the CloseIncidentRequest. I have the CloseIncidentRequest working successfully on the case update post event  but on the create I keep getting the "Need to start a transaction before commit" exception.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue, or has anyone got this running on the case create post event? I have seen posts around changing from synchronous to asynch - and if I change the plugin to run asynch, that does work - but ideally I want this to run this synchronously, so that the user can see that the case has been resolved when pressing save.

```csh
private const int IncidentResolutionStatus_Closed = 2;
private const int IncidentStatusCode_ProblemSolved = 5;

Entity resolution = new Entity("incidentresolution");
resolution["subject"] = "Case Resolved";
resolution["incidentid"] = new EntityReference("incident", IncidentId);
resolution["timespent"] = timespent;
resolution["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(IncidentResolutionStatus_Closed);

CloseIncidentRequest closeincidentRequest = new CloseIncidentRequest() 
{ 
  IncidentResolution = resolution, 
  Status = new OptionSetValue((int)IncidentStatusCode_ProblemSolved) 
};

service.Execute(closeincidentRequest);
```

Comment: James, The code above works fine on the update event, its the same code being called by the create event.

Comment: Are you catching exceptions anywhere?

Comment: There is try catch block around the code above - this is where the "Need to start a transaction before commit" exception is being thrown.

Comment: Can you include that in the code then please.

Answer (score 0):

Try resolving the case manually (through the CRM interface) and you probably will get the same error (like me).

If so it's not related to your plugin code (or SDK), but on some missing information when you created the case.

Check if on the case you are trying to resolve there is no missing required field. In my case the error was that the Client name was null (there was a client record but its name was null) and it was causing the error.